# PHP Form cant output value

Tags: php

Im new to php and tryed to output one of the input (radio) values.When i used `$_POST` to output i got Undefined index error/notice and when i used `var_dump` on `$_POST` i got `array(0) { }`.How could i output values / what might be the problem ?

```
require('connect.php'); 
?>

<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
   <?php
   $kusimus = $db->prepare('SELECT k.kusimus FROM kusimus AS k JOIN kusimus_valik AS kv ON k.Kusimus_id = kv.Kusimus_id WHERE k.Is_active = 2');
   $vastused = $db->prepare('SELECT kv.valik FROM kusimus AS k JOIN kusimus_valik AS kv ON k.Kusimus_id = kv.Kusimus_id WHERE k.Is_active = 2');
   $kusimus->execute();
   $vastused->execute();
   $result2 = $vastused->fetchAll();
   $result = $kusimus->fetchAll();
    ?>

    <?php echo '<b>'.$result[1][0].'</b><br>'; ?>

    <?php if(!isset($result2[0][0])){
      echo '';
    }else{
      echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$result[1][0].'" value="'.$result2[0][0].'">'.$result2[0][0].'<br>';
    } ?>



    <?php if(!isset($result2[1][0])){
      echo '';
    }else{
      echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$result[1][0].'" value="'.$result2[1][0].'">'.$result2[1][0].'<br>';
    } ?>

    <?php if(!isset($result2[1][0])){
      echo '';
    }else{
      echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$result[1][0].'" value="'.$result2[2][0].'">'.$result2[2][0].'<br>';
    } ?>


    <?php if(!isset($result2[3][0])){
      echo '';
    }else{
      echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$result[1][0].'" value="'.$result2[3][0].'">'.$result2[3][0].'<br>';
    } ?>

    <?php if(!isset($result2[4][0])){
      echo '';
    }else{
      echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$result[1][0].'" value="'.$result2[4][0].'">'.$result2[4][0].'<br>';
    } ?>


    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>



    <input type="submit" value="Vasta">


</form>

<?php
  var_dump($_POST);
 ?>
  </body>
</html>



 <?php
    $db = null; 


  ?>
```

Comment: your form output code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a switch statement instead of all of those if and else statements. You have to specify what variable you want to use var_dump on. $_POST isn't a variable. $_POST['var'] would be an example of a variable.

I seriously hope this code isn't going to be deployed.

Also, if you want more people to take you seriously, focus on improving your spelling, grammar, and punctuation before you focus on programming.

Comment: If you see any spelling, grammatical or punctuation errors please feel free to correct them by editing.